# Is there tool that can port or compile excel VBA code to C#?

Tags: c#, excel, compilation, vba

I don't know much about .net, but I am working on a project where a requirement is to port some  Excel VBA code embedded in spreadsheets to standalone C# .

Are they any tools that could automate (or semi-automate) this port or compile? How well do they work?

Comment: Will the C# code still use spreadsheets? Or is the idea to remove Excel from the solution completely, and have what the spread currently does done by a stand alone C# application?

Comment: The C# solution will be totally separate from the spreadsheets, ideally.

Answer (score 7):

No. Your best bet, if it's not alot of code is to do it by hand.

Otherwise, you mileage might vary. You might try converting the VBA to VB.NET and then use a [tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to convert that to C#.

[Converting Code from VBA to Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490(office.11).aspx)

[Ten Code Conversions for VBA, Visual Basic .NET, and C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164018(office.10).aspx)

Comment: +1. If I may also add. . . On "how well do they work?", quite well for what they do, but there **will** be considerable development work required to get the VBA to VB port to run, more to get it working correctly.

Comment: +1 Do it by hand, even if it is lots of code! If it's good code then it will use Excel to do some of the work, but the C# won't have the Excel object model so it won't work any more. If it's not good code then it might do it all without Excel, but then why would you want to port bad code?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but thought I would complete it as I :

### Case 1: Converting VB to C#

If you need to convert your code to C# use Telerik's web code converter:
http://converter.telerik.com/. Simply paste your VBA code (make sure you are not using Excel specific functions or variables like Range, Worksheets etc.) and convert. You should be able to easily re-use the code in your C#.NET project in Visual Studio.

If you want to make the library re-usable in Excel (make it COM-visible) [check-out this post here.](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-use-c-sharp-in-excel-vba/)

### Case 2: Converting VBA to VB.NET

If you don't need to make the DLL COM-visible simply create a VB.NET project in Visual Studio, compile and fix any found compilation errors :).

Otherwise, if want the DLL to be automated directly from Excel - I recently created an Add-In that does just that. It creates a COM-visible DLL directly from your Workbook (just select your VBA Functions) and pastes the required load procedures into your workbook as well. [Find it here.](http://www.analystcave.com/vba-compiler-add-in-to-vb-net/)

Answer (score -1):

Try using FlexCel.NET from www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp and they also have non-commercial version.

Comment: From their website: "100% managed code Excel file manipulation engine & Excel & PDF report generation for .NET and Windows Store". That's not what the question asked for.